# La base de datos no recibe señal de modificacion en mi base de datos laravel

Tags: java, html, laravel, base-de-datos

quiero comentarles lo que me esta pasando. el problema es que tengo la base de datos en donde en una de las tablas tengo como estructura configurada en categorías como por ejemplo. nombre, apellido, pago billetera. entre otras. el problema es que yo en pago billetera tengo como tipo tinyint(1) en donde el personalizado es 0 ya que el 1 es afirmativo y el 0 es negativo al momento de dar orden o no al uso de la billetera, el problema es en el momento del formulario en donde se creo el espacio o sección en el Billetera. en donde cuando selecciono con el tipo input checkbox en donde no toma modificación de lo que yo le quiero decir, es decir si selecciono tomaría el value: 1 que es cuando quiero que al momento de enviar el formulario quiera que cobre por billetera y si no lo selecciono se supone que queda por defecto ósea 0 que seria negativo la activación de billetera..

acá les dejo las líneas del formulario del problema en cuestión..

```
                            <div className="form-group"> 
                                <label htmlFor="extras">OPCIONES ADICIONALES ----- </label>
                                <input type="checkbox" className="form-control" name="use_wallet" id="use_wallet" value="1"/> Billetera
                            </div>
```

esto esta en base de laravel y esta en un archivo .js en donde toma html en configuración también .. no logro solucionarlo y probé hasta con varios input type y ninguno me deja.. o quizás tengo que darle permisos en la base de datos o en algún archivo por defecto en laravel.

espero su ayuda y le agradecería mucho que me ayudaran

La expectativa es que se pueda solucionar y pueda avanzar en esta edición